# how to set date from javascript to html <input type="date"/> element

Tags: javascript, html, date

can anyone please tell me how to set date  from javascript to HTML  element, Is it possible to do this because it is working with   tag but not with  tag ,
actually I have a requirement where I want a user to choose a date  from one input element and it will automatically set date in another date input element with a 1-year extension.

For example, if I choose a date from the first input as 02/16/2018 then it should automatically fill another date input as 02/16/2019.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `value` attribute of an input element will contain the date. SO select the original element, get it's value. Then select the element the date has to go to and change that inputs value to the value of the first element. Since you show no code where you have issues with, we can't help debug your code, only suggest things to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it in an other way:

```js
document.getElementById('1').addEventListener('change', function() {
 var date1 = document.getElementById('1');
        var dateSplit = document.getElementById('1').value.split("-");
        dateSplit[0] = parseInt(dateSplit[0]);
        dateSplit[0] = dateSplit[0] + 1;
        dateSplit[0] = dateSplit[0].toString();
        var date2 = document.getElementById('2').value = dateSplit[0] + "-" + dateSplit[1] + "-" + dateSplit[2];
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="date" id="1">
    <input type="date" id="2">  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, That is exactly what I was asking. Thanking you very very much.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

```js
$('#field1').on('change',function(e) {
  $('#field2').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" Id="field1"/>
<input type="date" Id="field2"/>
```

Comment: he wants 2019 in the second box.

Comment: Convert value to date and extract year, date and month. And increment year by 1, use Date constructor and set value using val()

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```js
const { format } = dateFns

function getDate() {
  var oldDate = document.getElementById("oldDate").value;
  var date = new Date(oldDate)
  var newDate = new Date(date.getFullYear()+1,date.getMonth(),date.getDay())
  document.getElementById("newDate").value = format(newDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.29.0/date_fns.js"></script>
<input type="date" onChange="getDate();" id="oldDate" />
<input type="date" id="newDate" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use https://momentjs.com/ to get the desired date and fill with `$('selector').val(newdate)` to another date input;